# Having trouble adding JScrollpane to my tbody

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to my my tbody scrollable with jscrollpane. Since jscrollpane adds a div, I'm not sure that this is possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you set jScrollPane to tbody, your table lose their native structure. But if you set 'max-height' and 'display' CSS properties, you got jScrollPane container with scrollable tbody's content.

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout making a pseudo-table? It's nasty, but it'll work:

```
<div class="imatable">
  <table class="thead">
    <tr>...</tr>
  </table>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <table class="tbody">
      <tr>...</tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, just apply it to the wrapper `<div>`.

Why exactly are you looking to do? We might figure out an alternate solution.

Comment: ahh! thank you for the suggestion. I need to have it semantic so I'm not sure this will be my final solution. Thanks for all the help. My goal is to have a sortable table with a scrolling tbody using tablesorter and jscrollpane.

Comment: I see. You can do the scrolling part with just a normal table, as you can just set a max-height for the `<tbody>`. As for sorting, I'm *sure* there's a plugin that works well with tables...

Comment: yeah, lol it's so basic that's the thing. jscrollpane is a requirement unfortunately. I think your above solution will work tho

Comment: Oh, that makes a bit more sense. I was wondering why you'd reinvent the wheel by using that plugin...